# Why does pd.concat change the resulting datatype from int to float?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, concatenation

I have three dataframes: timestamp (with timestamps), dataSun (with timestamps of sunrise and sunset), dataData (with different climate data). Dataframe `timestamp` has datatype `"int64"`.

`timestamp.head()
       timestamp
0  1521681600000
1  1521681900000
2  1521682200000
3  1521682500000
4  1521682800000`

Dataframe `dataSun` has also datatype `"int64"`.

```
 dataSun.head()
         sunrise         sunset
0  1521696105000  1521740761000
1  1521696105000  1521740761000
2  1521696105000  1521740761000
3  1521696105000  1521740761000
4  1521696105000  1521740761000
```

Dataframe with climate data `dataData` has datatype `"float64"`.

```
dataData.head()
           temperature     pressure  humidity
    0     2.490000  1018.000000      99.0
    1     2.408333  1017.833333      99.0
    2     2.326667  1017.666667      99.0
    3     2.245000  1017.500000      99.0
    4     2.163333  1017.333333      99.0
    5     2.081667  1017.166667      99.0
```

I want to concatenate these three dataframes in one.

```
dataResult = pd.concat((timestamp, dataSun, dataData), axis = 1)
dataResult.head()
       timestamp       sunrise        sunset  temperature     pressure     
0  1521681600000  1.521696e+12  1.521741e+12     2.490000  1018.000000   
1  1521681900000  1.521696e+12  1.521741e+12     2.408333  1017.833333   
2  1521682200000  1.521696e+12  1.521741e+12     2.326667  1017.666667   
3  1521682500000  1.521696e+12  1.521741e+12     2.245000  1017.500000   
4  1521682800000  1.521696e+12  1.521741e+12     2.163333  1017.333333   
5  1521683100000  1.521696e+12  1.521741e+12     2.081667  1017.166667   

weatherMeasurements.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 7188 entries, 0 to 7187
Data columns (total 6 columns):
timestamp      7188 non-null int64
sunrise        7176 non-null float64
sunset         7176 non-null float64
temperature    7176 non-null float64
pressure       7176 non-null float64
humidity       7176 non-null float64
dtypes: float64(5), int64(1)
```

Why `pd.concat` has changes the datatype of the values `DataSun`? I have tried different ways to concatenate the dataframes. For example, I concatenated only `timestamp` and `dataSun` in one dataframe, then I concatenated resulted dataframe with `dataData`. But it was the same result. 
How can I concatenate three dataframes and secure the datatypes?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Because of this -

```
timestamp      7188 non-null int64
sunrise        7176 non-null float64
...
```

`timestamp` has 7188 non-null values, while `sunrise` and onwards have 7176. It goes without saying that there are 12 values that are *not* non-null... meaning they're NaNs.

Since NaNs are of `dtype=float`, every other value in that column is automatically upcasted to float, and float numbers that big are usually represented in scientific notation.

That's the *why*, but that doesn't really solve your problem. Your options at this point are

1. drop those rows with NaNs using `dropna`
2. fill those NaNs with some default integeral value using `fillna`

(Now you may downcast these rows to int.)

3. Alternatively, if you perform `pd.concat` with `join='inner'`, NaNs are *not* introduced and the dtypes are preserved.

   ```
   pd.concat((timestamp, dataSun, dataData), axis=1, join='inner')

          timestamp        sunrise         sunset  temperature     pressure  \    
   0  1521681600000  1521696105000  1521740761000     2.490000  1018.000000   
   1  1521681900000  1521696105000  1521740761000     2.408333  1017.833333   
   2  1521682200000  1521696105000  1521740761000     2.326667  1017.666667   
   3  1521682500000  1521696105000  1521740761000     2.245000  1017.500000   
   4  1521682800000  1521696105000  1521740761000     2.163333  1017.333333   

      humidity  
   0      99.0  
   1      99.0  
   2      99.0  
   3      99.0  
   4      99.0
   ```

With option 3, an inner join is performed on the indexes of each dataframe.

Comment: You are absolutely right. I didn't check the code carefully. I have already corrected it and it works right. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 6):

As of pandas 1.0.0 I believe you have another option, which is to first use [convert_dtypes](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.convert_dtypes.html). This converts the dataframe columns to dtypes that support pd.NA, avoiding the issues with NaNs discussed in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49940609/10682164) answer.