# Why does pd.concat change the resulting type from int to object?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, types, concatenation

I'm parsing several csv files with Pandas and the concatenating them into one big dataframe. Then, I want to `groupby` and calculate the `mean()`.

Here's a sample dataframe:

`df1.head()`

```
   Time  Node  Packets
0     1     0        0
2     1     1        0
4     1     2        0
6     1     3        0
8     1     4        0
```

`df1.info(verbose=True)`

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 27972 entries, 0 to 55942
Data columns (total 3 columns):
Time       27972 non-null int64
Node       27972 non-null int64
Packets    27972 non-null int64
dtypes: int64(3)
memory usage: 874.1 KB
None
```

Then I concatenate them (for the sake of simplicity, three dataframes)

```
df_total = pd.concat([df1, df2, df3])
```

`df_total.info(verbose=True)` results in

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 83916 entries, 0 to 55942
Data columns (total 3 columns):
Time       83916 non-null object
Node       83916 non-null object
Packets    83916 non-null object
dtypes: object(3)
memory usage: 2.6+ MB
None
```

Finally, I try :

```
df_total = df_total.groupby(['Time'])['Packets'].mean()
```

and that's where the error `pandas.core.base.DataError: No numeric types to aggregate` appears.

While I understand from other posts such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49940511/pandas-concat-changes-datatype) that Pandas changes the `dtype` because of the `non-null`, I couldn't solve my issue with the proposed solutions.

How do I fix this?

Comment: You might want to try `returned_errors = [] <br>results = [] <br>for group in  df_total.groupby(['Time'])['Packets']:<br> try:<br> results.append ([group[0], group[1].mean()]) <br>except: <br>returned_error.append(group)` That should give you results for any groups that don't have an error (if any) and tell you which groups caused an error.

Answer (score 2):

I found another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12844529/no-numeric-types-to-aggregate-change-in-groupby-behaviour) that mentions that dataframes have to be initialized with a dtype, otherwise they are of type object

```
Did you initialize an empty DataFrame first and then filled it? If so that's probably
why it changed with the new version as before 0.9 empty DataFrames were initialized 
to float type but now they are of object type. If so you can change the 
initialization to DataFrame(dtype=float).
```

So I added `df_total = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Time', 'Node', 'Packets'], dtype=int)` to my code and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

```
 df_total.info(verbose=True)
```

Your this statement gives info as object, so there is problem in concatenation every value is not int and so mean of object is not possible.